# Why Cannot an OpenStack instance obtain a MAC address?

Tags: networking, openstack

We have set up OpenStack servers on two server hosts connected to a router and switch. We've divided the switch into two VLANs:

- VLAN2: 10.2.xx
- VLAN3: 10.3.xx

Our network architecture includes VMware-created nodes:

- Controller: Connected to:
- placement
- nova-API
- neutron-server
- glance
- keystone
- cinder.
- Five Compute Nodes: Each communicates with nova-api and neutron-server and also connects to VLAN2 and VLAN3.

The compute nodes have necessary services such as `openstack-nova-compute` and can connect to both VLANs.

#### Issue

After successfully creating instances in the dashboard, the instances are running fine but can't connect to the network. In the "Network" -> "Port" section, the status remains "Build". Upon querying logs, it's evident that the `neutron-linuxbridge-agent` on the compute node fails to identify the instance NIC.

#### Relevant Logs

```
[user@controller ~]$ openstack network create  --share --external \
>   --provider-physical-network provider \
>   --provider-network-type flat provider
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| Field                     | Value                                |
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| admin_state_up            | UP                                   |
| availability_zone_hints   |                                      |
| availability_zones        |                                      |
| created_at                | 2023-09-03T14:03:35Z                 |
| description               |                                      |
| dns_domain                | None                                 |
| id                        | 9196400a-dda7-4806-b343-c0ef77abf2e6 |
| ipv4_address_scope        | None                                 |
| ipv6_address_scope        | None                                 |
| is_default                | None                                 |
| is_vlan_transparent       | None                                 |
| mtu                       | 1500                                 |
| name                      | provider                             |
| port_security_enabled     | True                                 |
| project_id                | d95d6f1287f04732bd9c4c6abe87f3a5     |
| provider:network_type     | flat                                 |
| provider:physical_network | provider                             |
| provider:segmentation_id  | None                                 |
| qos_policy_id             | None                                 |
| revision_number           | 1                                    |
| router:external           | External                             |
| segments                  | None                                 |
| shared                    | True                                 |
| status                    | ACTIVE                               |
| subnets                   |                                      |
| tags                      |                                      |
| updated_at                | 2023-09-03T14:03:35Z                 |
+---------------------------+--------------------------------------+
[user@controller ~]$ openstack subnet create --network provider \
> --allocation-pool start=10.3.4.1,end=10.3.4.128 \
> --dns-nameserver 223.5.5.5 --gateway 10.0.0.1 \
> --subnet-range 10.0.0.0/8 provider
+----------------------+--------------------------------------+
| Field                | Value                                |
+----------------------+--------------------------------------+
| allocation_pools     | 10.3.4.1-10.3.4.128                  |
| cidr                 | 10.0.0.0/8                           |
| created_at           | 2023-09-03T14:03:44Z                 |
| description          |                                      |
| dns_nameservers      | 223.5.5.5                            |
| dns_publish_fixed_ip | None                                 |
| enable_dhcp          | True                                 |
| gateway_ip           | 10.0.0.1                             |
| host_routes          |                                      |
| id                   | f77dd93b-b3dc-46b1-8386-b4a2f613f830 |
| ip_version           | 4                                    |
| ipv6_address_mode    | None                                 |
| ipv6_ra_mode         | None                                 |
| name                 | provider                             |
| network_id           | 9196400a-dda7-4806-b343-c0ef77abf2e6 |
| project_id           | d95d6f1287f04732bd9c4c6abe87f3a5     |
| revision_number      | 0                                    |
| segment_id           | None                                 |
| service_types        |                                      |
| subnetpool_id        | None                                 |
| tags                 |                                      |
| updated_at           | 2023-09-03T14:03:44Z                 |
+----------------------+--------------------------------------+
[user@controller ~]$ . admin-openrc
[user@controller ~]$ openstack port list 
+--------------------------------------+------+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
| ID                                   | Name | MAC Address       | Fixed IP Addresses                                                       | Status |
+--------------------------------------+------+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
| 0b71ee0f-9ccd-43bd-a4c6-0abacfaa5be5 |      | fa:16:3e:39:b2:d0 | ip_address='10.3.4.40', subnet_id='f77dd93b-b3dc-46b1-8386-b4a2f613f830' | BUILD  |
| cfb73285-4add-4eb0-91ab-ac68819c47a3 |      | fa:16:3e:43:1b:f8 | ip_address='10.3.4.1', subnet_id='f77dd93b-b3dc-46b1-8386-b4a2f613f830'  | BUILD  |
+--------------------------------------+------+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+
[user@Compute-Node-3 ~]$ sudo nmcli d
DEVICE          TYPE      STATE         CONNECTION     
ens34           ethernet  Connected     ens34          
ens35           ethernet  Connected     ens35          
lo              loopback  Unmanaged     --
```

#### Error Logs in `linuxbridge-agent.log`

[OneDrive link for `linuxbridge-agent.log`](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlmLimZdMrExglByMJvHzIK4WwAR?e=ZLk7aD)

#### Network Agent List

```
[user@controller ~]$ . admin-openrc 
[user@controller ~]$ openstack network agent list
+--------------------------------------+--------------------+-----------------+-------------------+-------+-------+---------------------------+
| ID                                   | Agent Type         | Host            | Availability Zone | Alive | State | Binary                    |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------+-----------------+-------------------+-------+-------+---------------------------+
| 18b075eb-d309-40f2-971a-000242a65025 | Linux bridge agent | network-service | None              | :-)   | UP    | neutron-linuxbridge-agent |
| 4c347266-16a0-4aa3-a9df-830224736185 | Metadata agent     | network-service | None              | :-)   | UP    | neutron-metadata-agent    |
| 62e12e3e-fcd4-4b78-be16-a60d881cc5f2 | Linux bridge agent | Compute-Node-4  | None              | :-)   | UP    | neutron-linuxbridge-agent |
| 95cbadbd-ec54-42f4-96c7-81ce1f0ddbd4 | Linux bridge agent | Compute-Node-5  | None              | :-)   | UP    | neutron-linuxbridge-agent |
| b4430f05-80d7-49ea-83fe-2e14db97da67 | DHCP agent         | network-service | nova              | :-)   | UP    | neutron-dhcp-agent        |
| d3fe4062-30bb-4fb5-9618-0d07877142c3 | Linux bridge agent | Compute-Node-3  | None              | :-)   | UP    | neutron-linuxbridge-agent |
| e90f054c-e2a8-4c87-a986-7f01a365912b | Linux bridge agent | Compute-Node-2  | None              | :-)   | UP    | neutron-linuxbridge-agent |
| f3cc749d-5e40-42ad-b103-11b9657aee16 | Linux bridge agent | Compute-Node-1  | None              | :-)   | UP    | neutron-linuxbridge-agent |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------+-----------------+-------------------+-------+-------+---------------------------+
```

#### `neutron.conf`  in Network Node

```
[database]
connection = mysql+pymysql://neutron:********@10.2.3.1/neutron
 
[DEFAULT]
core_plugin = ml2
service_plugins =
transport_url = rabbit://openstack:********@10.2.3.1
auth_strategy = keystone
notify_nova_on_port_status_changes = true
notify_nova_on_port_data_changes = true
 
[keystone_authtoken]
www_authenticate_uri = http://10.2.3.4:5000
auth_url = http://10.2.3.4:5000
memcached_servers = 10.2.3.1:11211
auth_type = password
project_domain_name = default
user_domain_name = default
project_name = service
username = neutron
password = *******
 
[nova]
auth_url = http://10.2.3.4:5000
auth_type = password
project_domain_name = default
user_domain_name = default
region_name = RegionOne
project_name = admin
username = nova
password = *******
 
[oslo_concurrency]
lock_path = /var/lib/neutron/tmp
```

#### `neutron.conf`  in Compute Node

```
[DEFAULT]
transport_url = rabbit://openstack:********@10.2.3.1
auth_strategy = keystone

[cache]

[cors]

[database]

[healthcheck]

[keystone_authtoken]
www_authenticate_uri = http://10.2.3.4:5000
auth_url = http://10.2.3.4:5000
memcached_servers = 10.2.3.1:11211
auth_type = password
project_domain_name = default
user_domain_name = default
project_name = service
username = neutron
password = ********

[oslo_concurrency]
lock_path = /var/lib/neutron/tmp

[oslo_messaging_amqp]

[oslo_messaging_kafka]

[oslo_messaging_notifications]

[oslo_messaging_rabbit]

[oslo_policy]

[privsep]

[profiler]

[ssl]
```

#### `linuxbridge_agent.ini`: Provider Network (Option 1 in official guiance)

```
[DEFAULT]

[linux_bridge]
physical_interface_mappings = provider:ens34
[vxlan]
enable_vxlan = false
[securitygroup]
enable_security_group = true
firewall_driver = neutron.agent.linux.iptables_firewall.IptablesFirewallDriver
```

#### `neutron-server.log` in Network Node

```
2023-09-03 22:03:35.100 64478 WARNING neutron.services.revisions.revision_plugin [req-8891ef64-0e90-47c8-aea4-03cd8f70c1c9 f39040c33d3b4e09bcad1e305b9b02e7 d95d6f1287f04732bd9c4c6abe87f3a5 - default default] Could not find related network for resource <neutron.db.rbac_db_models.NetworkRBAC[object at 7f235c0d1fd0] {project_id='d95d6f1287f04732bd9c4c6abe87f3a5', id='36c749a5-591d-41a7-840a-d834c8fc9f6c', target_project='*', action='access_as_shared', object_id='9196400a-dda7-4806-b343-c0ef77abf2e6'}> to bump revision.
2023-09-03 22:03:35.160 64478 INFO neutron.db.segments_db [req-8891ef64-0e90-47c8-aea4-03cd8f70c1c9 f39040c33d3b4e09bcad1e305b9b02e7 d95d6f1287f04732bd9c4c6abe87f3a5 - default default] Added segment 78d46700-7f55-47df-a124-5ee0cd3c7da4 of type flat for network 9196400a-dda7-4806-b343-c0ef77abf2e6
2023-09-03 22:03:35.387 64478 INFO neutron.wsgi [req-8891ef64-0e90-47c8-aea4-03cd8f70c1c9 f39040c33d3b4e09bcad1e305b9b02e7 d95d6f1287f04732bd9c4c6abe87f3a5 - default default] 10.2.3.1 "POST /v2.0/networks HTTP/1.1" status: 201  len: 830 time: 0.6657691
2023-09-03 22:03:44.096 64479 INFO neutron.pecan_wsgi.hooks.translation [req-71c84e97-f4f5-4617-9b41-3f3e8e66c4cb f39040c33d3b4e09bcad1e305b9b02e7 d95d6f1287f04732bd9c4c6abe87f3a5 - default default] GET failed (client error): The resource could not be found.
2023-09-03 22:03:44.098 64479 INFO neutron.wsgi [req-71c84e97-f4f5-4617-9b41-3f3e8e66c4cb f39040c33d3b4e09bcad1e305b9b02e7 d95d6f1287f04732bd9c4c6abe87f3a5 - default default] 10.2.3.1 "GET /v2.0/networks/provider HTTP/1.1" status: 404  len: 316 time: 0.4845898
2023-09-03 22:03:44.212 64479 INFO neutron.wsgi [req-6ed45ac2-0f25-4ba4-a191-dd931c4d7f80 f39040c33d3b4e09bcad1e305b9b02e7 d95d6f1287f04732bd9c4c6abe87f3a5 - default default] 10.2.3.1 "GET /v2.0/networks?name=provider HTTP/1.1" status: 200  len: 828 time: 0.1054440
2023-09-03 22:03:44.741 64479 INFO neutron.wsgi [req-73a13804-ebe5-49a9-aa1d-3413dcea6867 f39040c33d3b4e09bcad1e305b9b02e7 d95d6f1287f04732bd9c4c6abe87f3a5 - default default] 10.2.3.1 "POST /v2.0/subnets HTTP/1.1" status: 201  len: 817 time: 0.5180576
2023-09-03 22:03:47.977 64480 INFO neutron.plugins.ml2.plugin [req-79bc1d89-40f3-4e51-9459-7cb081b44cdc - - - - -] Attempt 1 to provision port cfb73285-4add-4eb0-91ab-ac68819c47a3
2023-09-03 22:03:48.661 64480 INFO neutron.plugins.ml2.plugin [req-40955894-03d8-4a72-a41e-68c61c07f92f - - - - -] Attempt 1 to provision port cfb73285-4add-4eb0-91ab-ac68819c47a3
```

Comment: Can you share the error messages from the logs?

Comment: I have add it ,thank you!

Comment: The linuxbridge-agent ist down: `Linux bridge agent Agent out of sync with plugin!`. Can you confirm with `openstack network agent list`? And you'll probably need to share your neutron config as well.

Comment: Thanks for your patient guidance, I just uploaded them.

Comment: I meant all the neutron configs, including linuxbridge_agent.ini as that's the one reporting the error.

Comment: OK，the `linuxbridge_agent.ini` file  I uploaded is in my Compute Node1.

Comment: Is there anything useful in the neutron-server.log? Can you add that as well?

Comment: There are many texts in it, so I choose something useful and uploaded it on OneDrive.

Comment: The logs you uploaded are from today, your error messages from the linuxbridge-agent are from August 29th. Reproduce the issue and add only the relevant neuron logs to your question (and update those from linuxbridge-agent so the timeline is consistent).

Comment: Sorry, it took me some time to update a lot of texts.

Comment: To get some more attention you could also ask this question in the openstack-discuss mailing list, I don't have a clue at the moment.